# Как сгруппировать данные за 2 года в 1?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Пока сгруппировал по году:

```
date_part('year', redireсt_log.created) as year
...
group by year
```

В итоговой выборке есть как данные за 2015 год, так и за 2016. Можно ли вывести их вместе средствами SQL?

UPD: Получаю

```
COUNT("redirect_log", "id", "clicks").
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду суммировать за 2 года?

Comment: Что значит группировать? Допустим есть группа 2015-2016 а как тогда другие группы? По какому признаку хотите построить группы?

Comment: Можно по чётным годам, например, сделав or.

Comment: Firepro, да, в общем за 2 года в итоге (пока только они есть)..

Comment: nick_n_a, хочу общее количество за все время.

Comment: Общее к-во за время - не нужно групировать. Гораздо быстрее будет работать условие отбора, например ` where date_part('year', redireсt_log.created)  in (2015,2016)`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите делать суммирующую выборку за 2 года, просто установите границы дат через WHERE year IN (2015, 2016) или year > 2015 (хотя в вашем случае можете не ставить, если у вас всего за 2 года выборка в базе) и уберите условие GROUP BY, а использование агрегирующих функций (COUNT, SUM и т.д) позволит Вам получить результат по всему интервалу.

Comment: "Можно ли вывести их вместе средствами SQL": вместе - это в одном поле суммировать их данные, за 2 года, иначе у меня получается 2 поля :)

Comment: У вас второе поле year? Если вы убираете группировку, то можете и поле date_part('year', redireсt_log.created) as year - убрать)

Comment: Тогда будут сотни несгруппированных данных за каждый день, за 2 года. Мне нужно одно поле, общая сумма за все время.

Comment: Тимур, Если вы вызываете любую агрегирующую функцию, в вашем случае COUNT(*) в SELECT, то у Вас при выводе будет только одна строка, независимо от того, сколько там строк :)

Comment: column "redireсt_log.created" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function :(

Comment: Покажите весь запрос.который у Вас получился. Желательно его прикрепить текстовым файлом на какой-нибудь сервер.

Comment: http://vk.com/doc144178797_437744120?hash=fddea3d69ba8423d96&dl=2f1372280f6b4a7c6a